# Failed to redirect execvpe() stderr to file with dup2()

Tags: c++, redirect, dup2

As shown below, I want to redirect stderr from execvpe() to file. But the resulted `/tmp/test` does not contain expected content.

```
// redirect.cpp
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("/tmp/test", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd != -1) {
        dup2(fd, 1);
        dup2(fd, 2);
        close(fd);
    }
    char* argv[] = {"ls-not-exist","-al","/etc/passwd",(char*)0};
    char* envp[] = {"PATH=/bin", 0};
    int ret = execvpe(argv[0],argv,envp); 
    printf("ret:%d %d\n", ret, errno);

    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is like

```
$ ls-not-exist -al /etc/passwd
ls-not-exist: command not found
```

But the actual output is

```
$ ./redirect; cat /tmp/test
ret:-1 2
```

which does not contain stderr content.

I also tried with other function(`execvp()`) in `exec()` family, but also failed.

Comment: Finally figure it out. execvpe() will first check if argv[0] exists in PATH. If not exists, the command will not be executed. So I could not capture expected stderr. Instead, using `sh -c "ls-not-exist -al /etc/passwd"` works for my case.